# Finding the quarter value in data values using standard sql bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, quartile

I would like to have Q1 and Q3 for the frequency column using standard sql.

Table name : table.frequency

Sample data:

[image: image here]

What I did is:

```
SELECT (ROUND(COUNT(frequency) *0.25)) AS first_quarter,
(ROUND(COUNT(frequency) *0.75)) AS third_quarter
FROM table
```

And the results are not as I expected:

First quarter = 30577.0
Third quarter = 91730.0

Expected outcome is the 1st and 3rd quarter value for frequency column. Example :
First quarter = 14
Third quarter = 51

Comment: could you explain the formula you have used to derive the values 14 for first quarter and 51 for third quarter

Comment: I used the formula 1/4* n+1 . but not sure if its right.

Comment: `cume_dist() `?

Comment: What do YOU mean by "standard SQL"?  Please tag with the database you are usingn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches, but a simple one uses `ntile()`:

```
select max(case when tile = 1 then frequency end) as q1,
       max(case when tile = 2 then frequency end) as q2,
       max(case when tile = 3 then frequency end) as q3       
from (select t.*, ntile(4) over (order by frequency) as tile
      from t
     ) t;
```

There are *definitely* other approaches, such as `percentile()` or `percentile_cont()`.  But this is a simple method using standard SQL.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee49dd5ea30d23f2799ca6daa0cad07d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @nsw . . . I don't see a table name in your query.  That is just a placeholder for your table.

Comment: any idea why i received Expected end of input but got keyword FROM  for the 2nd FROM ?

Comment: @nsw . . . No.  Your question doesn't even have a database tag.  You can set up a db<>fiddle, if you like, but this answers your question.